# pattern matching in Bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

Here is an example to get different parts of a filename

```
bash-3.2$ pathandfile=/tmp/ff.txt  
bash-3.2$ filename=$(basename $pathandfile)  
bash-3.2$ echo $filename    
ff.txt    
bash-3.2$ echo ${filename##*.}     
txt    
bash-3.2$ echo ${filename%.*}    
ff
```

I was wondering what does ## and % mean in the patterns. How is the patten matching working?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manpage for `bash` says:

> ${parameter#word}
>   ${parameter##word}
>
> > **Remove matching prefix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just  as
> >               in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with  the
> >               shortest  matching  pattern  (the  `#` case) or the longest matching pattern (the
> >               `##` case) deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the  pattern  removal  operation  is
> >               applied  to  each  positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
> >               list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted  with  `@`  or  `*`,  the  pattern
> >               removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion
> >               is the resultant list.
>
> ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
>
> > **Remove matching suffix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just  as
> >               in  pathname  expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
> >               value of parameter, then the result of the  expansion  is  the  expanded  value  of
> >               parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal
> >               operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
> >               resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with  `@`  or  `*`,  the
> >               pattern  removal  operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
> >               expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Regarding `*`: In other words, if the above isn't working, remember to use `*` in your prefix or suffix, as `##` and `%%` will otherwise look for exact matches only.

Answer (score 3):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html:

> ${string##substring}
>
> Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.

and

> ${string%substring}
>
> Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

Answer (score 2):

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html.

> - `${string##substring}`
>
>   - Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.
> - `${string%substring}`
>
>   - Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

Comment: And a mnemonic for '#' (hash) is 'head', and a mnemonic for '%' (percenT) is 'tail'.

Comment: And, on US English qwerty keyboards, "#" is to the *left* of "$" and "%" is to the *right* of "$".