# Remove everything in a pipe delimited file after second-to-last pipe

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

How can remove everything in a pipe delimited file after the second-to-last pipe? Like for the line

```
David|3456|ACCOUNT|MALFUNCTION|CANON|456
```

the result should be

```
David|3456|ACCOUNT|MALFUNCTION
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `|(string without pipe)|(string without pipe)` at the end of each line:

```
sed 's/|[^|]*|[^|]*$//' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, something like

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{NF=NF-2; print}' inputfile
David|3456|ACCOUNT|MALFUNCTION
```

(or) use `cut` if you know the number of columns in total, i,e `6 -> 4`

```
cut -d'|' -f -4 inputfile
David|3456|ACCOUNT|MALFUNCTION
```

Comment: not working. Printing entire file as it is. is there anything I am missing here? tried as awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{NF=NF-2; print}' /home/user/file.txt

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine under `cygwin` maybe? Which Linux and which `awk` version are you using? Can you output `awk --version` ? and `which awk`

Comment: @Satya: can you do `dos2unix < /home/user/file.txt`, before running the `awk` command?

Comment: The `one-true-awk` (AKA `nawk`) does not reevaluate the record until an assignment is made to one of its fields.   The following wil work as intended: `{NF-=2;$1=$1}1`

Answer (score 0):

The command I would use is

```
cat input.txt | sed -r 's/(.*)\|.*/\1/' > output.txt
```

Comment: You want to remove 2 pipes. Shouldn't you use `\|[^|]*\|[\|]*$` ?

Answer (score 0):

A pure Bash solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]] ; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line%|*|*}"
done <inputfile
```

See [Reading input files by line using read command in shell scripting skips last line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17268113/4154375) (particularly the [answer by Jahid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397497/4154375)) for details of how the `while` loop works.

See [pattern matching in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2488196/4154375) for information about `${line%|*|*}`.